# How convert a partial project VS2010 database to VS2012 database project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, database-project

I would like to upgrade VS 2010 database project to VS 2012.

Project is spitted by many partial projects due to many customization and configurations.

Is there any feature similar to partial project in VS 2012, that can be used in this case, to build database with many db blocks?